# Monoids as categories; does this construction have a name?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, monoid

We can view a monoid $M$ as a category with a single object. However, there is another way to make $M$ into a category. Take the elements of $M$ as objects, and define $\mathrm{Hom}(x,y)$ to be set of all triples $(x,y,a)$ such that $ax=y$. Define composition such that $(y,z,b) \circ (x,y,a)  = (x,z,ba)$ and identity arrows by $\mathrm{id}_x = (x,x,1).$

I'd like to learn more about this construction. Does it have a name?

Comment: If M is a monoid, and more generally we consider it as acting on a set X on the left, we often call it a _translation groupoid_.

Comment: @TylerLawson, wouldn't that only be appropriate if $M$ happens to be a group? Otherwise, we needn't get a groupoid at all.

Comment: I don't think that anybody would object to calling it a translation category instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's going on here is that you've allowed the monoid $M$ to operate on the set $M$, and you've successfully expressed this monoid action as a category.

For a general monoid $M$ acting on a set $X$, you can view the elements of $X$ as objects of a  category and use the elements of $M$ as arrows between the objects.

Comment: In the case of groups this is also known as the "action groupoid". See Brown's work for instance.